# How to show an image for five seconds and then show another one(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have my Java code, I have this layout where there is a `ImageView` and a `Button`, in my `Drawable` folders I have to images, What I want is: When the Button advance is Clicked, the `ImageView` will show the image(image1.png that is in the `drawable` folder) and the after 5 seconds show the other image(image2.png). The problem is that I don't know how to make that pause.

```
advance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
                  //TO WAIT 5 SCONDS...
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the default CountDownTimer
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

1. Set the first image
2. Start the CountDownTimer

set the new image in onFinish()

```
    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) { // 5000 = 5 sec

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     }

     public void onFinish() {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
     }
}.start();
```

**Edit:**

extra info: in the documentation, you can find

CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)

so the first parameter is the total time you want to have (in milliseconds, 5 sec = 5000 milis) and the second parameter is the interval. Here it's 1000 = 1 sec. This means that the timer will tick every second. So the onTick(long ) will be called every second (when the timer is running)

Comment: It worked, thanks... I just wonder what does the '1000' works for.

Comment: See the Edit. Explains what you need to know about it.

Comment: How to make it work for more than 2 images? I also do not want to hard code the resources, as the variables are not accessible inside the new object.

Comment: @AnkitSinghaniya The best thing you can do is to create an array of drawable resource ids and use that array, but this is still hard coded. If the images are drawables, they need to be hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

```
advance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
                Timer t = new Timer();
                t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                          image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                     }
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a  Handler: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)

```
advance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);

                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                    }
                }, 5000);

                }
    });
```